# ajax respsonse undefined object

Tags: ajax, object, properties, response

Although there is many posts with similar question,i couldnt managed to resolve it.

I can see at Console of my browser my object returns ok as array.
when i alert data.AlliasName i get undefined.

my json returns 
{"data": [{"id":1,"FirstName":"101","LastName":"101","AlliasName":"101","Address":"kentro","Type":"1"}]}

[image]

```
$.ajax({
      url: urlreq,
       dataType: "json",
       success:  handleData
  });
  function handleData(data) {
                alert(data.AlliasName);
                console.log(data);
                //do some stuff
            }
```

I ve tried also puting the alert into success, data[0].AlliasName and eval func,always same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data being returned contains a *property* called "data", which is an array, so the way to access this would be:

```
function handleData(data) {
    console.log(data.data[0].AlliasName);
}
```